# Show & hide different <img> with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

I have this html code created with javascript.

```
$(".timeline-points").prepend( "<div class='vd-cues''></div>" );

$(".vd-cues").css('left',p/d*100+"%"); //bullets position on the progress bar

$(".timeline-points").prepend("<img class='preview-img' src='./vids/out/"+f+"' height='80px'></img>");

$(".preview-img").css('left',p/d*100-7+"%");
```

And what I want is to get the `preview-img` when the mouse is over a specific `vd-cues`. So, when the mouse is over the first `vd-cues` the first image should be `show`, and on the second `vd-cues` the second image should be `show`, and so on...

I've tried several approaches, but I can't get this to work. I think it's because I'm creating HTML with jQuery, and also because I'm calling the function `OverBullets` to soon.

http://jsfiddle.net/7R36G/1/

Comment: _"different `<img>` with same id"_ - It's not valid html to have the same id on multiple elements. To select multiple similar elements give them a common class.

Comment: First of all, sse classes instead of IDs if want to apply same CSS. Please provide a jsfiddle with your HTML, respectively.

Comment: JSFiddle has been update, and the question and code too. However I got another problem. The css left I'm using is updating the other classes...

Comment: @zppinto Here is the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7R36G/2/ But note that all the images have the same `left` value in this example.

Comment: Thank you, but your approache shows all the `preview-img`, and not only a specific one! And yeah, that's my problem now! All the classes have the same left value... Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to confess that I'm a little frustrated because no one really helped me with my question. However I thank you all for your support and attention to the classes.

I have solved my problem with parent and child approach, and also with a simple line of CSS.

However I have to dismiss the class approach you've suggested because I don't know how to specify the left value to each of the class, like it happens when I use ids.

So what I did was changed the second `prepend` to `vd-cues` and so I've created a child `preview-img` with a parent `vd-cues`. Then I've used the "#parent:hover #child" to display the correct image when mouse is over, and voilá :)

http://jsfiddle.net/7R36G/3/

Answer (score 0):

`id` is unique in HTML document.

Better approach is to use `class` and hide those

```
<img class="preview" src="...">
<img class="preview" src="...">
```

jQuery

```
$('img.preview').hide()
```

Comment: Please check my JSFiddle! I've made the changes, but now the css->left is applied to all the classes, and I still can't find how to really solve my question problem...

Answer (score 0):

id is unique in HTML document.
Better use name. So that you can achieve what you need. 
you can get all the elements by using

```
getElementsByName("name")
```

this will return all the elements with same name.
Check its visibility if it is visible change it to not visible state and change the hidden thing to visible state. 
That's it. Done.